# Tumblr RSS feed not working with YQL

Tags: rss, tumblr, yql

Why Tumblr's own RSS feed (`<blogname>.tumblr.com/rss`) is not working with YQL which is W3C validated feed for some Tumblr profiles? It is returning Connection Failure! Yahoos [own blog](https://yahoodevelopers.tumblr.com/rss) is not working with the YQL query.

Below is the query:

```
select * from rss(0,100) where url = "https://yahoodevelopers.tumblr.com/rss" limit 5 offset 0
```

It is returning with Connection Failure with status 307.

Comment: Presumably, Tumblr banned YQL

Answer (score 0):

I have found what is the problem. The Tumblr profiles with https:// don't work with YQL and the http:// URL's are working fine.

Comment: Please remember [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).