# YQL does not work with Tumblr https URL

Tags: xml, rss, tumblr, yql, yahoo-api

I am facing a problem when I am trying to implement RSS feed with Yahoo feed reader api and the YQL. The problem is when I am running the YQL with Tumbler blog which has the http protocol it is working fine, but if I use a Tumblr profile which is using https protocol is not working. It is returning with Connection Failure with status 307.

Below is some working and non working URL's tested with YQL console.

Working:

http://just-shower-thoughts.tumblr.com/rss

http://whitemenwearinggoogleglass.tumblr.com/rss

http://digdaga.tumblr.com/rss

Not working:

https://thevaliantcollectiontriumphblr.tumblr.com/rss

***https://yahoodevelopers.tumblr.com/rss***

https://lamontlibrary.tumblr.com/rss

Even the yahoo developers blog is also not working.

The URL can be test on the below link:

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console

Insert the below query where it says

YOUR YQL STATEMENT Permalink

select * from rss(0,100) where url = "tumblr URL" limit 5 offset 0

Below is the link to the query:

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+rss(0%2C100)+where+url+%3D+%22https%3A%2F%2Fyahoodevelopers.tumblr.com%2Frss%22+limit+5+offset+0

The Return statement:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="0" yahoo:created="2017-11-21T05:45:36Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <diagnostics>
        <publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
        <redirect
            from="/ec?url=https%3a%2f%2fyahoodevelopers.tumblr.com%2frss&amp;t=1511243136&amp;ttl=60&amp;sig=IHlLP2zCNE9HS13hRVWP0g--~D" status="307"><![CDATA[https://yahoodevelopers.tumblr.com/rss]]></redirect>
        <url error="Connect Failure" execution-start-time="0"
            execution-stop-time="366" execution-time="366"><![CDATA[https://yahoodevelopers.tumblr.com/rss]]></url>
        <user-time>367</user-time>
        <service-time>366</service-time>
        <build-version>2.0.217</build-version>
    </diagnostics> 
    <results/>
</query>
```

Have anyone faced the same problem?

Please get me some suggestions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the description of the error(s) you're facing. Also, it would be more helpful if you add a link with the YQL console link sample for each one of these rss.

Comment: I have added the return statement. If you want to execute any of the above link just go to the  link https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console and run the YQL I mentioned above.

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/yqlfeeds.shtml) can help you, however, my advice is try to use other way to get such information. I don't think YQL is stable enough and may fail without notice. Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tumblr RSS feed not working with YQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181130/tumblr-rss-feed-not-working-with-yql)

Comment: The problem is happening only with the HTTPS URL of Tumblr otherwise it is fine.